# VB.NET - auto-hide (docking) panel

Tags: vb.net

Is there any option in VS 2015 to create a docking panel, such as Toolbox\Server Explorer\Data Source in VS ?

Comment: [**SplitContainer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) -- [**SplitContainer.Panel1Collapsed**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel1collapsed(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @VisualVincent, not sure about your answer. What does this do?

Comment: Mostly what you asked for. It is a container containing two different panels which can be resized using the splitter in between. If you set `Panel1Collapsed` to True the left panel will be hidden, only showing the right one. Add one to a form and try it out. -- Though to be able to move (dock) a panel/control you would have to create your own custom control with those features included. There is currently no such feature in any basic .NET control.

Comment: Not sure if this is what i need. I have a MDI parent form, and on left i have a Treeview control on panel. Right side is meant for forms that will open in a MDI client. Can I open forms in right side of this split container ?

Comment: I believe so. Each side will behave as a normal `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` so you can add any control to it. I'm not familiar with how MDI forms work, or if they're the same as what I am about to say, but you can add a form to it by setting the form's `TopLevel` property to False and then call `SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(yourForm)`

Comment: After doing some research I came up with that you can only add MDI forms to top level windows. So to be able to place forms in the right/left panel of the SC you must add it as I instructed above. This will pretty much be your solution in any case.

Comment: I'll try this, maybe i can manage it. I'll let you know for results, but It will take some time, im a VB.Net beginner.

Comment: I tried, forms open inside panel, but problems occur...If form is maximized, how can i maximize right panel only - to fit form window ?...And when i use Panel1Collapsed to True, how should i bring it back (prefer tab button on left side, possible?)...I changed MDI form to regular.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to make the panel fit the window. When the window is maximized the window will fit to the parent. -- To bring the panel back you just set `Panel[1 or 2]Collapsed` to False again. Can be done by placing buttons in toolbars, menus, on the main form, etc. You can put a SplitContainer in another SplitContainer if you want to have more "splittings" and be able to include a button on one side of your form.

Comment: I see, I tried many things, but right panel cant be maximized to form. I'll try more, but If  It can't be done, then split container is no use for me.

Comment: Only option i see so far is to dock it to parent form, but when maximized, left panel border gets wider, which is also not nice looking.

Comment: It's hard for me to see the full picture, but you would have to know the size of the form to be able to size-to-fit its parent. As said when you maximize the form it will fit to the parent, thus the parent won't know the wanted size of the form. -- If you set the `MinimumSize` property of the form you could use that to (when you add the form to the panel) set the SplitContainer's `Panel[1 or 2]MinSize` property to the form's `MinimumSize.Width`.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, you have showed me the path. I figured out simple solution... First you have to dock split container to parent form. Then you can use Fixed Panel property and lock one of the panels, so it stays same width allways, that's It. Though there are many problems left to solve all my issues, but that will be opened in another thread. Thanks for help !!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to post an answer - you can use split containter, which you can then design as needed.